# Cannot access Java resource when packaged in Mac app bundle

Tags: java, macos, javafx, native, app-bundle

I am accessing a Java resource to use in my JavaFX application..

```
URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/image.jpg");
File file = new File(resource.getFile());
if (!file.exists()) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("No image: " + file)
}
```

Everything works fine and the resource is found when running as the Java application.

However, now I am bundling my JavaFX application in a native Mac app using zenjava's Maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>
            com.seaniscool.foobar.FooBar
        </mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I build with the native plugin using:

```
mvn clean jfx:native
```

Now, when I run the application by running the Mac `.app` file, this resource can no longer be resolved to a file. `getResource` returns this URL:

```
jar:file:/Projects/foobar/target/foobar.app/Contents/Java/foobar-jfx.jar!/image.jpg
```

But it cannot be found when used as a `File` path.

Comment: Why do you need it as a `File`?

Comment: ..? To do things with it?

Comment: What _kind_ of things? You already have access to the `InputStream` through `openStream()` on the `URL` object. It's not actually a file in the `jar`.

Comment: A embedded resources is not a File, it can not be accessed as one. Instead, you need to either use the URL reference passed back by getResource or the InputStream reference passed back by getResourceAsInputStream. The reference you have is nothing more then a pointer to Zip entry within your Jar file...

Comment: Wow, I never knew that. I've always treated them as 'file references' or something. I'll reconsider how I access the content then, cheers! PS: you should post a response so I can accept and others can learn from my mistakes eh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `URL` in

```
URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/image.jpg");
```

is a `uniform resource locator`. In this case it locates the resource identified by `/image.jp` in a `.jar` file. Which, as it turns out, is a type of `zip` file.

```
jar:file:/Projects/foobar/target/foobar.app/Contents/Java/foobar-jfx.jar!/image.jpg
```

A zip entry is not a file, it's just a bunch of bytes that have some meaning to a zip file. If you want to get those bytes as an `InputStream`, inflated, you can simply call

```
InputStream inputStream = resource.openStream();
```

[See the javadoc of `URL#openStream()`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29)

Comment: @Sean You are welcome. Note that, with Java 7 NIO package, you can do some funky things to access jar/zip entries as `FileSystem` `Path` objects. [See an example here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) This helps if you need to remove/add things to the jar. The entry is _still_ not a file, however.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the fully qualified name meaning : `/package1/package2/.../file-name` not `/file-name` directly